# Process Printing works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, printing, process

I am trying to print a PDF in a C# MVC application with the orientation set to landscape mode. This currently works in my dev environment but when I move it to our web server, that is running IIS 8, it does not work. I can see Adobe reader open as a background process but that's it. I've read multiple posts that say to impersonate an account with unlimited access, I did this but not luck.

Here is my code

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Verb = "PrintTo";
info.Arguments = "Test Copier";
info.FileName = Server.MapPath(@"\Temp_Pdf\test.pdf");
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
```

Comment: What's your app pool running under? Does that account have access/permissions for the printer?

Comment: My app pool is impersonating an administrator account. Yes it has access to the printer